# dataWithBytesNoCopy:length: memory management

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

I am using `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` method for creating `NSData` object from `bytes`.

```
-(NSData *)dataFromBytes
{ 
...
   void *data = malloc(bytes);
... 
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:bytes];;
}
```

From apple documentation:

> The returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it
>   on deallocation.

should i release return data object in caller function?

```
-(void)testFunction
{
NSAutoreleasePool *nsp = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSData *ldata = [mObject dataFromBytes];
NSlog(@"%@", ldata)//printing data
[nsp release];
NSlog(@"%@", ldata)//Not printing data //sometimes getting exc_bad_access

}
```

Comment: The memory management rules for the object don't change just because the object will take ownership of one of the arguments. Whether or not you release the object is still determined by the method's name, as prescribed in [the rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Comment: @PeterHosey thank you. I have one more question. why my application is working fine on 10.6 and 10.7(with release on returned data object).

Comment: its crashing sometimes on 10.5.

Comment: You're not guaranteed to get a crash when you do things wrong. It may work, it may crash, it may misbehave. The unpredictability of the outcome is itself a reason to make sure you do things correctly—occasional misbehavior is more frustrating than a consistent crash, and neither one makes you look good to the user. Releasing the object in that situation is wrong, on every Mac OS X version, regardless of what happens or doesn't happen afterward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: No, the caller should only release the returned data if it has retained it. In your `testFunction` you haven't retained it so you shouldn't release it.

**Longer answer**:  Firstly, the `dataFromBytes` method in your above code doesn't have a return value, presumably this should actually return `NSData *`.

Anyway, the `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` method returns an autoreleased `NSData` instance which is immediately being returned from the method.  We know that it is autoreleased because the method name doesn't contain init, new or copy. This means the caller is **NOT** automatically taking ownership of the returned data so it shouldn't release it (unless it retains it).

Ownership of the `data` that has been malloc'ed is taken over by the NSData object and shouldn't be freed. When the NSData instance is dealloc'ed it will free the memory that was malloc'ed.

In your, `testFunction` you are receiving the `NSData` object and printing it. Next you release the autorelease pool which will cause the autoreleased object to be released and dealloc'ed. You print it again but it has already been dealloc'ed which is dangerous (I'm surprised it doesn't always `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: Okay. thank you. why my application is working fine on 10.6 and 10.7(with release on returned data object).its crashing sometimes on 10.5